# HCL truth table conversion

Tags: hardware, boolean-expression, truthtable

I was assigned to convert the following truth table to H Boolean expression and simplify the expression as much as possible.

**Here is the table**

[image: Example]

I got for an answer
(!x^!y^!z)V(!x^!y^x)V(x^!y^!z)V(x^!y^z)

It seems a little long, is this as simplified as I can get?

I understand how to make the drawing of the truth table, but just do not understand if there is a better option for the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x z are not doing anything here. so !y